# Use SecureString password object in dsquery command authentication

Tags: powershell, securestring, dsquery

I have followed the following guide to create a [SecureString](https://www.pdq.com/blog/secure-password-with-powershell-encrypting-credentials-part-1/) password. 
Now, I need to log on to a foreign Domain Controller with the dsquery options -s (server) -u (user) and -p (password).

```
dsquery group -name $group -s $rmSrv -u $user -p $pass  | dsget group -members -expand -c -s $rmSrv -u $user -p $pass  | dsget user -samid -c -s $rmSrv -u $user -p $pass > $filename
```

When I enter the password in plaintext, I get authenticated.
Once using the SecureString object, I can not authenticate.
I have tried a few options, but could not get it running.

Do you have ideas?

Comment: `dsquery` is a command-line executable.  It can't interpret objects, just flat text, so you're going to need to convert your `securestring` to `plaintext` and pass it that way.

Comment: I suggest reading [this article](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2010/12/02/query-active-directory-without-writing-a-script/) to interact with `AD` using `powershell`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do that is to decrypt the `SecureString` object and get it as a string.

Here is a sample function:

```
function ConvertTo-String {
  param(
    [Security.SecureString] $secureString
  )
  try {
    $bstr = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($secureString)
    [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($bstr)
  }
  finally {
    if ( $bstr -ne [IntPtr]::Zero ) {
      [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ZeroFreeBSTR($bstr)
    }
  }
}
```

**Caution:** Decrypting a `SecureString` object bypasses the protections that `SecureString` objects provide.

If you insist on using the `dsquery` command, this is the only option, because it requires a plain-text password on its command line. This is inherently insecure.

Instead, I would recommend to use the Active Directory cmdlets that can use `SecureString` directly without the need to convert to plain-text.

Comment: Thank you for the hint with the AD cmdlets. I will try those.